# Logistic regression with r and stata

Tags: r, regression, stata, logit, convergence

I ran the same Logistic regression with R and STATA.

The regressors include many dummy variables.

In R, the code I used is

```
fit <- glm(formula = y ~ ., family = "binomial", data = df)
```

which reports the warning message:

```
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

In STATA, I simply ran

```
Logit y x1 - x20
```

and the reported table looks OK and the estimation seems to be reasonable.

Actually if I have only a few regressors, say only $x_1, x_2, x_3$, they report the same result.

I'm wondering why there could be such difference? In R, how to fix the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try increasing the number of iterations. See `?glm.control` for details.

Comment: Without additional details, we can only guess. Can you provide your data?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the `collinear` or `asis` options in Stata. Without them, Stata does some additional steps that `glm` doesn't. Might not be the answer, but I'd guess some kind of perfect predictor or collinearity kind issue.